# parse out JSON.parse(cookies[:cookie_name]) item into ruby variable

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, cookies

I need to access a specific string inside the cookie.

I am using:

```
@id = JSON.parse(cookies[:cookie_name])
```

and it returns a JSON object. What is the best way to access a specific item in the JSON object?

Here is example of the JSON object:

```
{"distinct_id"=>"12345", "$initial_referrer"=>"$direct", "$initial_referring_domain"=>"$direct", "__mps"=>{}, "__mpso"=>{}, "__mpa"=>{}, "__mpap"=>[], "mp_name_tag"=>"12345", "id"=>"12345"}
```

What I want from that object is the `distinct_id`.

Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks more like a Ruby hash than a JSON object (`JSON.parse` returns a hash as well).  If that's the case, wouldn't  `@id['distinct_id']` work?

Comment: My mistake. In the case of using `@id['distinct_id']` when would I call the JSON.parse to read the cookie?

Comment: I assumed the bit with the distinct_id was coming from the cookie?  What does @id contain after the call to JSON.parse?

Comment: sorry read it wrong. I get you completely so @id = JSON.parse(cookies[:cookie]) and then when I use the variable i just do @id['distinct_id'] 

thanks for your help.